# Compiling package with profiling enabled using GNU make

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, profiling

I am trying to compile a big package (Heasoft) with code profiling enabled. The package uses makefiles for setup.
I am enabling compilation with support for profiling with the (gcc) "-pg" flag through CFLAGS:

```
$ CFLAGS="-pg" make
```

The compilation runs till the following error between incompatible flags is raised:

`gcc: error: -pg and -fomit-frame-pointer are incompatible`

How am I suppose to deal with it? (Given that I am interested in profiling just some of the tools the package provides I ask the more objective questions below hoping them can be more easily answered)

- What is this "omit-frame-pointer" and is it really needed?
- Can I say to GNU make to avoid such conflicts, ignoring the command-line (in this case "-pg") flags?
- Can I tell GNU make which code (tools) I want to enable the profiling ("-pg") flag?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"omit frame pointer" does exactly that - it instructs the compiler to *not* save the [frame pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Stack_and_frame_pointers) into a CPU register if the compiler detects that the function does not need it (e.g. because it has no arguments and so does not affect the stack). This saves a little time on each call. Also it frees a register that can then be used for further optimizations.

On the other hand, tracking the function becomes impossible, so to enable debugging or profiling you need to restore it explicitly.

To do this, add `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` to the debug flags.

You may also have to disable all code optimizations with the `-O0` flag.